# Sharing Saved Queries in AD

Tags: active-directory

I created a Saved Query in AD on our domain controller. I thought everyone would see it, but only I do. How can I make sure everyone can see it [I mean admins].

I know that I can export the query, but there should be a way to do this besides exporting,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saved Queries are specific to the user that creates them. Export the query and disseminate it to the people you want to have it. They can then import it for themselves.

Comment: I can do that for this one case, but there has to be a way to create queries, or the equivalent of queries, and make sure all admins can see them.

Comment: There doesn't have to be a way. We may want a way, but that doesn't mean that there has to be a way. I may want a way to travel to the moon in a boat but that doesn't mean there has to be a way to do it. I'm being facetious of course, but my point is that there is unfortunately no way to share them other than to export them.